# How to Run Mythril tool using hardhat?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, blockchain, hardhat, mythril

1. Mythril fails to import remotely and all-time searches in the local file system - to solve this I used Hardhat to compile my contract - and hardhat compiled contract.
2. Now I am stuck on How to run Mythril on the contract using Hardhat to compile the solidity file.

```
npx hardhat compile // this comiles contract
myth -a FILENAME.sol --execution-timeout 10 //
```

**myth compiles file.sol using solc compiler and again giving import error - NOW HOW TO USE HARDHAT compiled solidity and RUN it on mythril.**

Answer (score 0):

It maybe too late to help you but I answer for the others.

As this github issue said, Mythril compiles solidity with solc.
https://github.com/ConsenSys/mythril/issues/1621

please set remappings to solc.json like

```
{
    "remappings": [ "@openzeppelin/=node_modules/@openzeppelin/" ],
    "optimizer": {
        "enabled": true
    }
}
```

and run

myth analyze contracts/hoge.sol --solc-json solc.json --execution-timeout 20